# How to handle Azure Frontdoor down?

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

Yesterday Azure Frontdoor was down for 45 mins, and i could not access my webapps.

Can I put something in front of my Azure Frontdoor to handle this downtime ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and ended up using Application Gateway when outages are happening. Depending on how you do this it can be manual or automatic.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

One of the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue,

- As of now i have not faced this issue .
  Please *Make sure that you have enabled below configuration in your routing rules* .

[image]

- Also in App service configuration by default its of ,  On this feature *for redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS* . Post that restart your webapp and run.

[image]

**NOTE:-** *In [**backend pool**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/routing-methods) there is configuration Priority and weight which have default value 1 and 50 ,Try to increase the weight as well which has max limit upto 1000.*

For more information please refer the below links for Azure front door configuration:-

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION**|[***CREATE FRONTDOOR FOR YOUR APPLICATION***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/quickstart-create-front-door#create-a-front-door-for-your-application).
- **BLOG**| [***Steps to implement Microsoft Azure Front Door Service***](https://blog.e-zest.com/steps-to-implement-microsoft-azure-front-door-service).

Comment: How would that solve the problem when dns for frontdoor is not working ?

Comment: AFAIK, You must delegate the domain provider's domain name system (DNS) to an Azure DNS if you're utilising Azure to host your DNS domains. For more information please refer this [**MS DOC**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain)